# if user.save not working in respond_to do |format| when fails validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

In my case it is pre_member instead of user. Even when it fails validations (pre_member does not save), it remains within the if block, does not go the the else block.

validations

```
class PreClubList < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :email, :enterprise, :member
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :enterprise, length: { minimum: 3 }
end
```

So if a user puts in one character for enterprise it still follows what's in the if block but doesn't save it.

action

```
  class PreClubListsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @member = PreClubList.new(pre_club_list_params)
    respond_to do |format| 
      if @member.save
        format.html
        format.js { render "create" } 
      else
        format.html
        format.js {"alert('form had following errors : #{@member.errors.full_messages});"}
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def pre_club_list_params
      params.require(:pre_club_list).permit(:email, :enterprise, :member)
    end

end
```

I'm using rails 4.1, simple_form

Comment: can you post your form?